# How to fit layout to the whole screen for Calculator?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am making a simple Calculator App, and I am unable to fit the layout to span the whole screen. I have a TextView, an EditText, and buttons and there is a bit of whitespace that remains below. I want my layout to span the whole screen like Android's Calculator.

My XML code file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.varun.calculator.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="2"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:lines="2"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textSize="20sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/seven"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="7"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/eight"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/seven"
                android:text="8"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nine"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/eight"
                android:text="9"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/four"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/seven"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/five"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/eight"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/four"
                android:text="5"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/six"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/nine"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/five"
                android:text="6"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/one"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/four"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/two"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/five"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/one"
                android:text="2"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/three"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/six"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/two"
                android:text="3"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dot"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/one"
                android:text="."
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/zero"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/two"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dot"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clear"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/three"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/zero"
                android:text="C"
                android:textSize="25sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/div"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nine"
                android:text="/"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mul"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/div"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/three"
                android:text="*"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sub"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/mul"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/clear"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="25sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/equal"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/dot"
                android:text="="
                android:textSize="25sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/sub"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/three"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="25sp" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please check the image linked here: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbwHh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xml might be help you, it will cover the whole page as per your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="2"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:lines="2"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


  </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/seven"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eight"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nine"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/div"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="/"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mul"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="*"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dot"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="."
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zero"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="C"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sub"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
       </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove from parent layout

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.varun.calculator.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="2"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:lines="2"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/seven"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eight"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seven"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nine"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eight"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/seven"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/eight"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/four"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/nine"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/five"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/four"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/five"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/one"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/six"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/two"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dot"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/one"
            android:text="."
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zero"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/two"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dot"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/three"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/zero"
            android:text="C"
            android:textSize="25sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/div"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nine"
            android:text="/"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mul"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/div"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/three"
            android:text="*"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sub"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mul"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clear"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="25sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equal"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dot"
            android:text="="
            android:textSize="25sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sub"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/three"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="25sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tried, didnt work, If you check the image, I want my = button to be aligned to the bottom. That is the space I want to get rid of.

Comment: This _android:layout_below="@id/mul"_ is wrong. It should be _android:layout_below="@+id/mul"_ and also that place at where you'r using `@id/xyz`. It should be replaced by `@+id/xyz`

Comment: @VarunJoshi Did u get??

Comment: No, I cant seem to stretch my layout to fill the screen :(

Comment: Did u make changes as i told? Share your screenshot?

Comment: yes, though I did not understand the changes required for the id field

Answer (score 0):

In relative layout instead of keeping `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` try keeping the value to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and i would suggest that you keep equal weight values for each one of them... Try doing that. And maybe if any more blank space is left after doing these steps then remove `android:padddingBottom`

Comment: So Simple! Haha can't believe I spent 4 hours trying to experiment with layout weights. Thanks!

Comment: Its OK, I often get stuck with these things aswell.